# Kali installation is without any applications

Tags: operating-systems, kali-linux

I have installed kali Linux, ran in few errors upon installing. Started kali and I did not had gui, so I ran apt-get update and upgrade and I recieved gui. But now I have no applications, not even terminal, what can I do?

P.S.I have installed Kali Linux 64-bit(installer) image, version 2020.1b.

Comment: You should provide additional details.  It’s unclear what version of Kali you have installed

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, should have thought of that. Edited it now.

Comment: Click on the Blue Dragon and select All Applications. I am posting this from within Kali 2020.2

Comment: I assume "no answer" means you clicked on the Blue Dragon and still did not see anything. Perhaps try reinstalling Xfce.

Comment: @John I reinstalled completely the OS and ticked only one GUI.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Kali forum, no one really managed to install 2020.x propoerly. (Me neither). The majority of users there seems to revert to 2019.4. 
See
https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?47126-Kali-2020-1-anyone-actually-have-it-installing-properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was ticking too many options on the step select applications and I accidentally selected 2 GUIs: `GNOME` and `XFCE` and it could not resolve it maybe. So for any one else out there getting error on this step just do not tick `GNOME`, leave it with the default kali GUI `XFCE` and the installation will be okay.